# P&T Checkboxes and Channel Form

Tags: custom-fields, channel-form, field-pack

I am having trouble displaying checkboxes for a P&T Field Pack Checkboxes custom field in a Channel Form (ExpressionEngine 2.7.1, Field Pack 2.1.1) using the {custom_fields} and {options} loop.

I've simplified this example, but using the following code nothing is displayed.

```
{custom_fields}
  {if field_name=='preferred_position'}
    {options}
      {option_name}
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        name="{field_name}[]"
        value="{option_value}"
      >
    {/options}
  {/if}
{/custom_fields}
```

And the corresponding Field Options:

```
1 : Driver
2 : Cook
3 : Bartender
```

In earlier versions of EE (back when it was Safecracker), my loop looked like this:

```
{preferred_position:options}
  {option_name}
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="preferred_position[]"
    value="{option_value}"
  >
{/preferred_position:options}
```

Are the P&T fieldtypes unsupported by {custom_fields}?

Comment: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24226/pt-dropdown-and-checkboxes-with-channel-forms

Answer (score 4):

Any time i've used it P&T fields so far i've gone with this syntax:

```
{field:preferred_position}
```

I haven't specifically used checkboxes, but I think its worth a shot.