# Output List of P&T Dropdown Field Options

Tags: field-pack, drop-down, pt-dropdown

I was hoping to output the available options in my P&T Fieldpack Dropdown field with a template (into a dropdown used to filter results) but am having no luck.

I've seen some folks referencing a tag pair like {options:papers_type} but I'm getting nowhere. Is anyone else familiar with how to do this?

Feels like I must be missing something. Merci!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Low Options](https://github.com/low/low_options) can output native and P&T dropdown options in your templates.

Comment: Nice little (secret) plugin Low :) I've never seen this on your site for some reason though, good to know about it!

Comment: While I wish this functionality was build into P&T fieldpack, this solves the problem. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like your missing anything, I've checke [the docs](https://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/dropdown/index.html) but they are a little spartan to say the least...

If yuo wanted to simply display the field within a {exp:channel:form} SAEF it seems [you can use the `{field:var_name}` syntax](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14446/pt-checkboxes-and-channel-form), you should also be abel to use [the variable tag pair syntax](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/#custom-field-tag-pair) within the Cahnnel Form. However it sounds like you just want to use the options in a custom dropdown as you mention 'a filter'

You still have some options, but if you're dead set on extracting the optoins from the P&T Dropdown on a Channel Field (rather than recreating them in a snippet/global variable or summin) you could roll your own PHP Sql query to get them or attempt to use the EE Template API to get the options/render the field again using PHP.

Let me know if you want a concise example, I'll have to knock one together. However in the meantime [these docs](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_fields.html) might get you on the right path...

**Edit**: Been a while since I dipped into the Channel Fields API, so I tried an example. The following snippet will get you the options (as a key => value array) for a P&T Dropdown, provided you know the Channel (1) and Field ID (3) :

```
<?php

  //instansiate the channel entries API
  ee()->load->library('api');
  ee()->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

  //assuming Channle has ID of 1
  $channelSettings = ee()->api_channel_fields->setup_entry_settings('1', array());

  //assuming dropdown is field ID of 3
  $fieldOptions = empty($channelSettings['field_id_3']['options']) : array() ? $channelSettings['field_id_3']['options'];
?>
```

Comment: Accepting this as the answer, since at the end of the day the main bit is that it's not an option built into the P&T dropdown. While the custom query is a good idea, [Low Options](https://github.com/low/low_options) did the trick for me.

Comment: Hi alsophil, Thanks but I actually think that Low's answer is deserving of the tick. It's less 'hacky' and is the solution you actually used!